# Is using an extension method for casting a bad idea?

Tags: c#, casting

I recently started on WPF, and I noticed that you have to do a lot of casting (especially with events). This is an aesthetic issue, but I was wondering how bad it would be if I'd use an extension method to cast, instead of using normal casting.

```
public static T Cast<T>(this object obj)
{
    return (T)obj;
}
```

This would mean I could prevent a few nested parantheses, and change:

```
Console.WriteLine(((DataGridCell)e.OriginalSource).ActualHeight);
```

to:

```
Console.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource.Cast<DataGridCell>().ActualHeight);
```

Are there any clear disadvantages that I might be overlooking? How disgusted will people be when they encounter this in code? :)

Comment: Note that `t1.Cast<T2>()` then means `(T2)(object)t1`, *not* `(T2)t1`. They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @hvd Yes, and that difference is potentially very bad with value types...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is similar in intent to [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx), so I wouldn't necessarily say that people will be disgusted.

> Are there any clear disadvantages that I might be overlooking?

The main disadvantage is that this will be an extension method available to *every single variable* in your code, since you're extending `System.Object`.  I typically avoid extension methods on `Object` for this reason, as it "pollutes" intellisense.

That being said, there are other disadvantages:

If you used this on an existing `IEnumerable`, you'd get a name collision with `Enumerable.Cast<T>`.  A file having your namespace included but missing a `using System.Linq` could easily be misunderstood by other developers, as this would have a very different meaning to the expected "`Cast<T>`" extension method.

If you use this on a value type, you're introducing boxing (pushing the value type into an object), then an unbox and cast, which can actually cause an exception that wouldn't occur with a cast.  Your extension method will raise an exception if you do:

```
int i = 42; 
float f = i.Cast<float>();
```

This might be unexpected, as `float f = (float)i;` is perfectly legal.  For details, see Eric Lippert's post on [Representation and Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).  If you do write this, I would definitely recommend adding a [class constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) to your operator.

I, personally, would just use parenthesis.  This is a common, language supported feature, and should be understandable to all C# developers.  Casting has the advantages of being shorter, understandable, and side effect free (in terms of intellisense, etc).

The other option would be to make this a normal static method, which would allow you to write:

```
Console.WriteLine(Utilities.Cast<DataGridCell>(e.OriginalSource).ActualHeight);
```

This eliminates the disadvantage of "polluting" intellisense, and makes it obvious that its a method you wrote, but increases the amount of typing required to use.  It also does nothing to prevent the boxing and unbox/cast issue.

Comment: Good that you mentioned `Enumerable.Cast`: naming the custom extension method `Cast` means that a missing `using System.Linq;` causes `enumerable.Cast<T>()` to silently compile wrongly and fail badly at runtime.

Comment: Of course, you could always name the method `CastSingle` or something instead to solve that. (I first thought `As`, but people might confuse that with the `as` operator.)

Answer (score 6):

The main disadvantage is that casting is well-known for every C# developer, while your `Cast<T>` method is just another not-invented here wheel. The next step, usually, is a set of extensions like `IsTrue`, `IsFalse`, `IsNull`, etc.

This is a syntax garbage.